# Word vectorization in natural language processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a data set. This data set consists of only words. I have to do the vectoring of these words. I've searched for word vectoring algorithms. Bag of words, word2wec, tf-idf Bag of words, word2wec, tf-idf are doing the process of vectoring the words in a sentences. But I don't have sentences. i have just words. So how do I make the process of vectoring the words?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is your goal? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is a data set consisting of only words. I need to convert these words into numerical data. Because I'm going to use these word vectors as input in an artificial neural network. @Blorgbeard

Comment: tf-idf is a way of vectorizing _documents_, not specifically sentences. Presumably your words are somehow organized into articles, paragraphs, headlines, recipes, something. tf-idf is a basic way of transforming those documents into a vectorized bag of words for the entire _corpus_

Comment: You just restated the question. Numerical data representing what? Are these just random words from a dictionary? What is your NN going to predict?

Comment: I have words with positive or negative meanings. For example; beautiful or ugly @Blorgbeard

Comment: Ok, well it sounds like you just have a big set of words with no context, so you won't be able to extract embeddings yourself. I suggest you find pre-trained embeddings and join them with your dataset. E.g. [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)

Answer (score 0):

**Spacy** has a library to get word vectors of **300** dimension.
You need to load a vector package as shown in the code. token.vector will give you the vector for one **single** word.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
token = nlp('Basketball')
print(token.vector)
```